# UIBarButtonItem, add a back button using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a back button to my webview app.

Looking through `UIBarButtonItem`, I can't seem to find a back button. See code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")!
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))

    let back = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Back, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.goBack))

    toolbarItems = [back, refresh]
    navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false

}
```

How do I add a back button to the toolbar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are forget too add `UIBarbuttonItem` in `navigationItem`

so you need to do code like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = toolbarItems // that show two right side button.
```

if you want to show back button at left side and refresh button at right side in `navigationbar` then you must be code like:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refresh
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back
```

That will be appear in you nevigation back button left side and refresh button right side

So your code something look like following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")!
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))

    //let back = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Back, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.goBack))

    let back = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",style: .Plain,target: webView,action: #selector(webView!.goBack))

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refresh
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back
    navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false

}
```

if you want to add multiple button at leftbarbutton then create one more `UIBarbuttonItem` object something like:

```
let undo = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Undo, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.undo))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [back,undo]
```

that will be display two left button on navigation bar

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I can't seem to understand exactly where I would place this code to add these respective buttons and their actions? Please see my code here: http://pastebin.com/Z99nmJqW -- could you kindly clarify?

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, the back button is showing an `undo` button, please see this line: `let back = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Undo...` -- that's where the problem is. How can I use a *back* button or symbol instead?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarification. `let back = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Back` does not exist. **.Back** is not a UIBarButtonItem option. This is why I used `.Undo` just as a test. My question is, *how* can I display a **back** button?

Comment: So, this code gives the following error: `Type 'UIBarButtonSystemItem' has no member 'Back'`...

Comment: back is not a default button provide by apple so for back button you need to create button like: `let b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",style: .Plain,target: webView,action: #selector(webView!.goBack))`